# Django Tweepy can't access Amazon S3 file

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, tweepy, django-storage

I'm using Tweepy, a tweeting python library, `django-storages` and `boto`. I have a custom `manage.py` command that works correctly locally, it gets an image from the filesystem and tweets that image. If I change the storage to Amazon S3, however, I can't access the file. It gives me this error:

```
 raise TweepError('Unable to access file: %s' % e.strerror)
```

I tried making the images in the bucket "public". Didn't work. This is the code (it works without S3):

```
filename = model_object.image.file.url
media_ids = api.media_upload(filename=filename)  # ERROR

params = {'status': tweet_text, 'media_ids': [media_ids.media_id_string]}
api.update_status(**params)
```

This line:

```
model_object.image.file.url
```

Gives me the complete url of the image I want to tweet, something like this:

https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/OrillaLibertaria/195.jpg?Signature=xxxExpires=1467645897&AWSAccessKeyId=yyy

I also tried constructing the url manually, since it is a public image stored in my bucket, like this:

```
filename = "https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/OrillaLibertaria/195.jpg"
```

But it doesn't work.

¿Why do I get the `Unable to access file` error?

The source code from tweepy looks like this:

```
def media_upload(self, filename, *args, **kwargs):
    """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload
        :allowed_param:
    """
    f = kwargs.pop('file', None)
    headers, post_data = API._pack_image(filename, 3072, form_field='media', f=f)  # ERROR
    kwargs.update({'headers': headers, 'post_data': post_data})


def _pack_image(filename, max_size, form_field="image", f=None):
        """Pack image from file into multipart-formdata post body"""
        # image must be less than 700kb in size
        if f is None:
            try:
                if os.path.getsize(filename) > (max_size * 1024):
                    raise TweepError('File is too big, must be less than %skb.' % max_size)
            except os.error as e:
                raise TweepError('Unable to access file: %s' % e.strerror)
```

Looks like `Tweepy` can't get the image from the Amazon S3 bucket, but how can I make it work? Any advice will help.

Comment: url is a method, not an attribute.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid how should I call it? If I do `model_object.image.file.url()` I get the error: `'S3BotoStorageFile' object has no attribute 'url'`

Comment: `model_object.image.url()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it works as an attribute like this: `model_object.image.url` . That gives me the complete url of the image. But I still get the error: `Unable to access file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs when tweepy attempts to get file size in `_pack_image`:

```
if os.path.getsize(filename) > (max_size * 1024):
```

The function `os.path.getsize` assumes it is given a file path on disk; however, in your case it is given a URL. Naturally, the file is not found on disk and `os.error` is raised. For example:

```
# The following raises OSError on my machine
os.path.getsize('https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/OrillaLibertaria/195.jpg')
```

What you could do is to fetch the file content, temporarily save it locally and then tweet it:

```
import tempfile


with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as f:
    name = model_object.image.file.name
    f.write(model_object.image.read())
    media_ids = api.media_upload(filename=name, f=f)
    params = dict(status='test media', media_ids=[media_ids.media_id_string])
    api.update_status(**params)
```

For your convenience, I published a fully working example here: https://github.com/izzysoftware/so38134984

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro. I have a problem though. I've been trying for a couple of hours to make this work. My code now is the same as yours, however, I still get the error `Unable to access file` . You can see my whole project on this repo, and the exact lines are here: https://github.com/Alejoss/CrHisoka/blob/master/hisoka/management/commands/tweet.py . Why do I get the error? I have no clue. But I suspect that `f` is `None` after `f.write(model_object.image.read())` . Any ideas?

Comment: i don't think f can be none; maybe it's empty? Your code looks solid, I'll try to check it out later tonight and give it a try. You may want to check your aws user has the s3 perms as required

Comment: I have managed to use your code to upload media and tweet, see details in the PR here: https://github.com/Alejoss/CrHisoka/pull/1 .