# TweepError at / Unable to access file: No such file or directory when I use can

Tags: django, cdn, tweepy, cloudinary

Hi I started a project which I use Django + tweepy When I wanna tweet with media I save my media in cdn my photo upload successfully on my cdn but tweepy say

> / Unable to access file: No such file or directory

my code :

```
        tweet_photo = form.cleaned_data.get('tweet_photo')
        photo = cloudinary.uploader.upload(tweet_photo,
                                               public_id=clean_text)
        media = photo['url']
        api.update_with_media(media, clean_text)
```

Thanks for your helping

Comment: Could you please share an example value for `photo['url']` that is passed which leads to this error?

Comment: https://res.cloudinary.com/aminsaberi/image/upload/v1628772873/sample.jpg
it gave the url of the photo which we uploaded before @Aleksandar

Comment: Does the `update_with_media` method call succeed if you pass a different URL (not from Cloudinary)?
In other words, just call this method and pass it an arbitrary URL of an image that is publicly accessible.

Comment: yes I used public url which I found in google images it gave same error @Aleksandar

Comment: Looking at the Tweepy docs, the `update_with_media` method expects a local filename and since you're passing a URL it causing it to return the error. Could you please check the following SO answer which goes over the process of first grabbing the remote image and saving it locally before passing that local file to `update_with_media` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134984/django-tweepy-cant-access-amazon-s3-file/38191531#38191531